# Terraform script for getting IP addresses for all GCP projects in my organisation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, spring-cloud-gcp, qualys

I want to scan all the IP addresses on my organization's GCP account and feed it to a file every week or so. How do I write a [Terraform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraform_(software)) script/code to pull those data from GCP and then send it to the Qualys API for scanning?

Comment: Terraform does not have a feature to scan IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks John. there should be gcloud command that does it, correct? Do you know anything about it.

Comment: There is no substitute for reading the documentation. Start here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no simple way to achieve that. You can find similar question and partial solutions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/941633/list-all-public-ip-addresses-used-in-all-projects-in-gcp).

But if you want a complete list of all IPs in organization, I would suggest starting with a method to list all [resources in organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/listing-all-resources#list_all_resources) or to use [Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory).

If you feel like this is a feature that should be available, you can [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/).